# Как выбрать все таблицы из бд кроме одной

Tags: php, mysql

Вывожу все имена таблицы из БД `SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname`
А нужно вывести все имена таблицы кроме одной, имя ей application.
Пробовал что-то типа '`SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname WHERE TABLES NOT IN 'application'`
Говорит мне что синтаксис не правильный. 
Ясен пень, я ведь второй день пхп в глаза вижу. 
Прошу прощения за елементарный вопрос но гуглить у меня не получаеться(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'another_db'
AND TABLE_NAME != 'application'
```

Comment: вот это приколюха, заработало но, если название таблицы написано на инглише то ее серавно выводит, а если переименовать  таблицу на кирилицу то все гуд. Походу что-то с кодировкой намутил. Но мне это не важно.Спасибо)

Comment: Зачем использовать like, когда совпадение точное?

Comment: @Firepro изменил.

Comment: @МаксимТесля у меня английские скрывает.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE `tables_in_<Название базы данных>` != 'application';
```

**Требования:** MySQL >= 5.0

[SHOW TABLES  синтаксис с официального сайта](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html)

Comment: $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname WHERE 'tables_in_<solarpowerdb>' != 'products'";
запрос работает но опять же выводит все таблицы из бд.
Попробую похимичить еще, вдруг заработает

Comment: попробовал еще через знак не равно <> , все равно паскуда не пашет

Comment: @МаксимТесля имя бд заключать в угловые скобки не надо, подставьте имя БД так же как во from. `"SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname WHERE 'tables_in_$dbname' != 'products'"`